# Non-ASCII charset as C string

Tags: c, character-encoding, gcc-warning

I am developing a software which has multi-language support. I have to use one byte character sets. That means I cannot use UTF-8 encoding format. My Encoding formats are these:

- ENG: ASCII
- UKR: KOI8-U
- ARA: ISO8859-6
- SPA: ISO8859-1

I use notepad++ as my editor. When I receive the translation for a new language, I just simply increase my array size and change encoding format of the C file to new language encoding format. For example, my array looks like this for different encoding types:

```
#define MAX_CHAR_PER_LINE 10
enum Langs {
    en,
    uk,
    es,
    ar
    MAX_LANG
};

// ASCII    
const char settingStr[][MAX_LANG][MAX_CHAR_PER_LINE] = {
    //...
    { "SETTINGS", "îáìáûôõ÷áîîñ", "AJUSTES", "ÇÙÏÇÏÇÊ" },
    //...
};

// KOI8-U
const char settingStr[][MAX_LANG][MAX_CHAR_PER_LINE] = {
    //...
    { "SETTINGS", "НАЛАШТУВАННЯ", "AJUSTES", "гыогогй" },
    //...
};    
// ISO8859-6
const char settingStr[][MAX_LANG][MAX_CHAR_PER_LINE] = {
    //...
    { "SETTINGS", "ففََّ", "AJUSTES", "اعدادات" },
    //...
};
```

When I check the C file with hex viewer, I then be sure that binary values of characters are correct according to specified encoding standards.
My problems are I am getting compile warnings as:

[image]

Also logical errors in run time.

Sample code for online gdb is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char settingStr[][4][10] = {
    //...
    { "SETTINGS", "ففََّ", "ÇÙÏÇÏÇÊ", "AJUSTES" },
    //...
};

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            printf("0x%02X,", settingStr[0][i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

I suspect that gcc preprocessor cannot parse these strings. Should I add some kind of compiler flag? I do not want to fill my array with hex values.

Comment: It's the text editor converting characters > 127 to those symbols, not the compiler. This used to be done with [code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) at one time. Obviously, you can't have more than one code page active at a time, so only one language (maybe plus English) can be used at a time. I also use Notepad++ which has a menu option "encoding" which you should set as Ansi. It isn't possible to have those arrays though, with Ansi and have them all reading correctly in the text editor.

Comment: Bad solution for your immediate problem: rather than writing `"ñññ"` do `"\xC3\xC3\xC3"` (or whatever).

Comment: Terminal will probably be UTF-8, so use UTF-8 for console output. (it is fine to use other encoding for other uses). But why you cannot use UTF-8? It seems a design problem (not treating strings as black boxes), and all major operating systems are already UTF-8  (not Windows) or are going in that direction (newer Windows). Counting characters or handling single character at a time is asking troubles.

Comment: You might consider using [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/).

Answer (score 3):

The compiler error message is misleading: the string `"ÇÙÏÇÏÇÊ"` is probably encoded in UTF-8 (by your editor or some other tool during transmission) and uses 14 bytes (plus a null terminator). The compiler points to the error (the 6th character in the string) but the terminal supports UTF-8 and the 14 bytes of `"ÇÙÏÇÏÇÊ"` only appear as 7 characters, misaligning the `^~~~~~~` output on the next line. The other string `"ففََّ"` is probably misencoded too, causing extra misalignment.

The problem is your editing environment: The translation was given back to you encoded in UTF-8, which is the de facto standard today, more precisely, it may have been encoded twice: the original ISO8859-6 1-byte encoding for arabic and reencoded in UTF-8 from ISO8859-1 by mistake.

You cannot easily mix different encodings in the same file. It is very confusing for everyone: the translator, the programmer, the compiler, the users...

Here are different options to avoid these issues:

- You should seriously reconsider the design choice and use UTF-8. The source code with all translations will be readable in all languages, which is safer and simpler to audit. Depending on the runtime environment, this might simplify or complicate the display.
- you could store the strings in a separate file for each translation, each encoded with the appropriate encoding and retrieve them at run time.  This is more friendly for translators but requires substantial changes in the software.
- you could encode the translated strings in ASCII with octal or hexadecimal escape sequences to avoid re-encoding issues. This will avoid re-encoding problems and any compiler misinterpretations with historic encodings used in Far-Eastern countries.  You can use a small program to encode strings in as C source code.